# Passing data between javascript

Tags: javascript

Want to link one javascript file in index and exports it function to another javascript file

Index.html

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

test.js

```
var config = {};

config.server_ip = "127.0.0.1";

module.exports = config; //Error, module not defined

console.log("Hello World, I should be showing up in chrome console");
```

show.js

```
var config  = require('./test');

console.log(config);
```

I want to run index.html and at the same time using node.js to run my show.js file.

Apparently I can only choose one, if I do not export, my console.log works, if i export, my console.log do not work.

Is there any other method to pass data like this?

Do note that the workflow has to be like this, and I do not want to link 2 javascript file into my index.html

I tried using import and export function via mozila guide, however it seems that chrome does not support that as well.

Comment: put that before exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run index.html and at the same time using node.js to run my show.js file.

If you want to use **NodeJS** to run the JavaScript, then you have to actually run it on NodeJS.

If you are loading the script through a `<script>` element in an HTML document then you are running it in the browser and not NodeJS (it is possible that you are using NodeJS to run a webserver that supplies the .js file to the browser as a static file, but that isn't the same as running it on NodeJS).

> ```
> console.log("Hello World, I should be showing up in chrome console");
> ```

If you want to display something in the Chrome console then you need to run it browser-side and not in NodeJS.

Browsers don't have native support for AMD style modules, so to use the approach you are taking you would need to add something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you! For my approach, I'm guessing that I have to follow the convention that has been pre-determine in requireJS documentation?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use a library then you have to use the API provided by that library.

Comment: May I know if there is a possible work around for this? In-fact I am actually halfway through my project and the given code above is a sample of what issue I am facing in my project. I am actually already using google map api to complete me project, whilst I realize that this is the only issue that kept me from completing it